# Compare 2 file names (including content if possible) from 2 different paths in a zip file

Tags: bash, shell, compare, zip, diff

Is there any way to compare filenames (include content if possible) from 2 different paths in a zip file using a shell script?

The files I want to compare:

- 1st zip file (A): Include another zip file(A.1), and the file I need to compare to is the file inside the zip file (A.1).
- 2nd zip file (B): Includes a folder, the file inside the folder is the file I need to compare with the file in the zip file (A.1)

Is there any script or code or command I can use to compare the file inside those zip files?

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of use case `diffoscope` was made for:

```
$ echo 1 > foo
$ echo 2 > bar
$ echo 3 > baz
$ zip 1.zip foo bar baz
  adding: foo (stored 0%)
  adding: bar (stored 0%)
  adding: baz (stored 0%)
$ rm baz
$ echo 4 > foo
$ zip 2.zip foo bar
  adding: foo (stored 0%)
  adding: bar (stored 0%)
$ diffoscope --no-progress 1.zip 2.zip 
--- 1.zip
+++ 2.zip
├── zipinfo /dev/stdin
│ @@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
│ -Zip file size: 430 bytes, number of entries: 3
│ --rw-r--r--  3.0 unx        2 tx stor 18-May-24 03:46 foo
│ +Zip file size: 294 bytes, number of entries: 2
│ +-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx        2 tx stor 18-May-24 03:47 foo
│  -rw-r--r--  3.0 unx        2 tx stor 18-May-24 03:46 bar
│ --rw-r--r--  3.0 unx        2 tx stor 18-May-24 03:46 baz
│ -3 files, 6 bytes uncompressed, 6 bytes compressed:  0.0%
│ +2 files, 4 bytes uncompressed, 4 bytes compressed:  0.0%
├── foo
│ @@ -1 +1 @@
│ -1
│ +4
```